# Android RatingBar rating is not set correctly

Tags: android, ratingbar

I use two RatingBars in my xml layout:

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.25"
    android:rating="4.25"/>

<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.25"
    android:rating="4.5"/>
```

Even though I set ratings to **4.25** and **4.5**, both RatingBars display wrong number of stars filled. On an Android 6 device it looks like this:

[image: ratingBars]

On an android 4.3 device, it looks like this:

[image: ratingBars]

But on xml design view, I can see 4.25 and 4.5 are set. Can anyone tell me why? I do not do anything with the rating bars in my code).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried setting rating from code?

Comment: @NoumanGhaffar I did not. I will try and see what happens.

Comment: @NoumanGhaffar I tired now and same thing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the problem is related to `android:progressTint ,android:progressBackgroundTint & android:secondaryProgressTint`.
Try to add following lines to your rating bar:

```
android:progressTint="Color1"
android:progressBackgroundTint="Color2"
android:secondaryProgressTint="Color3"
```

also try to add style to your rating bar as following:

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat"">
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/yourColor1</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/yourColor2</item></style>
```

and finally add a the following line in your rating bar

```
style="@style/RatingBar"
```

It will work for you.